# como obtener las relaciones echas en laravel en la respuesta enviada a vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, api, eloquent

Estoy queriando armar un sistema de comentarios aninados, si lo hago solamente con laravel ningun problema,ya que tengo hechas las relaciones en las migraciones y en los modelos,y puedo verificar si un comentario tiene una respuesta aninada usando la recursividad, el problema es que cuando envio estos datos hacia la respuesta que llega a vue , tengo que agregar a mi controlador ::with() porque sino a estas relaciones no las puedo llavar por ejemplo usando `post.comment` al menos  que en mi controlador ponga ::with('comment') , estoseria un mal menor si fuera que sé cuantas veces un comentario va a tener una respuesta aninada..por lo que si quiero obtener al respuesta de cada comentario en mi controlador tengo que agregar ::with('comment','comment.replies','comment.replies.replies).. les dejo el codigo de ejemplo

**migracion Post**

```php
 Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->integer('is_anon')->nullable();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

            $table->timestamps();


            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

        });
```

**migracion comments**

```php
 Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('comment');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('comments');
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

**modelo Post**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function comment() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->whereNull('parent_id');
    }
}
```

**modelo Comment**

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }

    public function parent() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function replies() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

con el controlador de esta manera si uso solamente laravel todo funciona bien.

**PostController**

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::where('id',$id)->first();
        return view('index',compact('post'));
    }
```

pero si quiero enviar esta respuesta a vue como dije antes no puedo acceder a las relaciones (post.comment) o (post.comment.replies) ect por lo que actualmente mi controlador esta asi..

```
 public function show($id)
    {

        return Post::where('id',$id)->with(['comment.user','comment.replies','comment.replies.replies'])->first();
    }
```

notese que tengo que agregar 'comment.replies','comment.replies.replies' para tener acceso en vue a los datos mas anidados... hay alguna manera de que todo funcione sin usar with() ?? cualquier informacion me es de mucha ayuda, o si tienen repositorios de ejemplos que solventen este problema, ya vi varios repositorios pero todos lo hacen de una manera distinta y ya estoy bastante confundido..

Comment: yo no entiendo tu problema.. pero menos entiendo que tiene que ver vue en todo esto...

Comment: que cuando hago el return Post::all() por ejemplo y estos datos los recibo en un array con vue para imprimirlos en pantalla cuado lo quiero imprimir  por ejemplo post.comment me dice que comentario no existe... pero la relacion esta hecha , y si en el controlador agrego Post::all() ->with('comment') ahora si puedo imprimirlo, caso contrario cuando hago el return a una vista blade no me hace falta usar with para acceder a los datos relacionados

Comment: La verdad no entiendo aquí donde está el problema, cargar de forma ambiciosa las relaciones de una entidad te va a retornar una colección de dos o más niveles y con vue solo deberás iterar en la vista, ahora si deseas evitar el uso de eager loading entonces construye por medio del query builder la consulta a través de joins, pero una vez más no identifico un error aquí

Comment: Pero el problema entonces es lo que manda tu back o o esta en vue??? tene en cuenta que una cosa es lo que mandas y otra como lo queres mostrar.. dividi el problema...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para no tener que repetir a mano la anidacion en el controlador

```
¿Post::where('id',$id)->with(['comment.replies','comment.replies.replies','comment.replies.replies,replies',etc])->first();
    }
```

lo que hice fue ir al modelo **Comment.php** y crear la recursividad de esta manera

```
 public function replies() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id')->with(['user','parent'])->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
    }

    public function allreplies(){
        return $this->replies()->with('allreplies');
    }
```

luego en el controlador hago una sola llamada

```
 public function getComments($id){
        $c = Comment::where('post_id',$id)->whereNull('parent_id')->with(['allreplies','parent','user'])->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(5);
        return $c;
    }
```